# Are droids' names unique?

Tags: star-wars, droids

Does each droid have a unique name or does that designation refer to an entire class of droid? To put it another way, is R2-D2 specifically the droid we see in the films, or are there hundreds if not thousands of R2-D2s across the galaxy? If not, it would seem that they would run out of names fairly quickly.

Comment: I'm not 100% convinced this should be closed as a duplicate, largely because (I think) it asks about droids in general; R2-D2 is just an example. So any example of two non-astromech droids that share 'names' would answer this question, but not the other.

Comment: As the OP I'm happy for the question to be closed - the information in the link has answered it. Yes, R2-D2 was an example but what was said there can be applied to C-3PO and the others.